# In rails 4.2, using Facebook oauth through devise, I want users to reauthenticate before changing their account details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, devise

I am in the process of adding social media oauth login and registration to an existing site. I've followed the overall process described here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Currently, if a user wishes to change their account profile (including email address, password, etc.) then they need to supply their existing password. This is to prevent cookie stealing style attacks, or damage caused by people leaving accounts logged in on public machines.

However, if a user has registered using Facebook then a randomised password is set behind the scenes and the user is not aware that a password exists in our system.

This could make the simple process of updating the user profile a confusing and off-putting task. How do we present the password to the user, and how do we explain that it's different to the Facebook password?

I would like to present a Facebook pop-up or interstitial to the user before they change their account details, to force them to re-authenticate using their Facebook password, but I can't immediately see a way of supplying multiple callback URLs, or passing form data.

Is there a feature or workaround that would let me achieve this?

Please let me know if including any code would help, but you can assume that I'm using a standard Rails app running Devise and the Facebook oauth strategy, with code snippets described in the link above.

Comment: Explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

Comment: Thank you. I did come across this, but what's not immediately clear is how to trigger this behaviour through the devise/omniauth API wrapper.

Comment: No idea what omniauth is so I have no idea

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will probably have to take apart the gems and work it out from first principles.